# ffmpeg change timecode metadata inside video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have problems to change timecode inside metadata of a video file "mov"

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mov -ss 0 -map 0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -timecode 01:20:10:00 -metadata:s:2:0 timecode=01:20:10:00 -metadata:s:1:0 timecode=01:20:10:00 -metadata:s:0:2 -metadata:s:0:2  timecode=01:10:10:00 output.mov
```

I need to put my own timecode to the file but this command not works.

The console give me:

```
  mov @ 00000225287fdc00] You requested a copy of the original timecode track so timecode metadata are now ignored
Output #0, mov, to 'convert_A019_02230134_C186.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    timecode        : 01:20:10:00
    encoder         : Lavf58.11.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (apcn / 0x6E637061), yuv422p10le(bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 122315 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 01:10:10:00
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422
      timecode        : 01:10:10:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-23T00:34:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 01:20:10:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-02-23T00:34:02.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 01:20:10:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  467 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  281452kB time=00:00:18.64 bitrate=123693.3kbits/s speed=71.1x    
video:278913kB audio:2531kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.002533%
```

I don't understand why it does not modify the timecode in the mov file. The old timecode remains.

Comment: Try `-timecode 01:30:10:00`

Comment: NO not works  also include this comando="ffmpeg -i " + nombre + " -ss 0 -map 0 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -timecode 01:20:10:00 -metadata:s:2:0 timecode=01:20:10:00 -metadata:s:1:0 timecode=01:20:10:00 -metadata:s:0:2 creation_time=01:10:10:00 -metadata:s:0:2  timecode=01:10:10:00"+ " convert_" + nombre

Comment: It was not clear in your original question that you wanted to apply 2 different timecode values.

Comment: Hello, No I will like change timecode to open in Davinci the problem is that after metadata change copy the   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)  when revise it is the same than before

Comment: Yes you have reason with -timecode 01:30:10:00  works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude the original timecode data using [negative mapping](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -map 0 -map -0:d -c copy -timecode 01:20:10:00 output.mov
```

Comment: Negative mapping is new to me, thank you, I learned something.
However, this doesn't solve the problem unfortunately. As the video track also has the timecode in my case.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, my GoPro video was starting at 9:02:07, so using the above command solution and using 00:00:00:00 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

How did the time code for H264 come from
How does this parameter exist during encoding

```
**Video
Format                                   : AVC

Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec

Format profile                           : High@L4.1

Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames

Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes

Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames

Format settings, Slice count             : 4 slices per frame

Bit rate mode                            : Constant

Bit rate                                 : 18.0 Mb/s

Width                                    : 1 920 pixels

Height                                   : 1 080 pixels

Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9

Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS

Color space                              : YUV

Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0

Bit depth                                : 8 bits

Scan type                                : Progressive

Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.362

Time code of first frame                 : 01:00:00:00



**Time code of first frame: 01:00:00:00**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLh1h.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).